# Android multiple stroke box in drawable xml

Tags: xml, android, shapes, drawable, stroke

I'm trying to achieve what amounts to effectively 2 strokes on a rectangle in a `<shape>` element in an android drawable xml.  A dark green outer line and a light green inner line, with a gradient fill in the center of it all.  My code currently looks like this:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">



<item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">

        <stroke android:width="3px" android:color="#477135" />
    </shape>

</item>
<item >
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient android:startColor="#81c557" android:endColor="#539942"
            android:angle="270" />

        <stroke android:width="1px" android:color="#a8d78a" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

I have tried applying android:top="3px" android:bottom="3px" to the 2nd item element, but when i add the right & left attributes, the entire thing doesn't render.  Note, this is all done within a ListView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, i believe i solved this with a work around.  it aint pretty but it works.  What i did was set an ImageView to have a background color set to the outer line color, gave it a padding of 1dip, then set the src of the ImageView to the drawable and i achieve the effect i was looking for.  That said, i'd much prefer to be able to do this all within the layer-list...